# Dispatcher playback stops after 10 minutes (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

So I have been developing a discord.js music bot. I am using [@discordjs/opus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus) and [ytdl-core-discord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-discord) so far and everything seems to be working perfectly when I run the bot locally from my machine. I am able to stream songs from YouTube and enjoy them without a hitch. However, when I host my bot on [repl.it](https://repl.it) (I am using the hacker plan), the bot will play music for about 10 minutes, after which the playback abruptly stops. The bot itself is functional, however the playback has stopped. I have tried debugging the issue myself and came across the following.

The error message is :-

```
{
    Error: aborted
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)
      at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:377:35)
      at node:net:661:12
      at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:578:7) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

which I obtained from :-

```js
dispatcher.on('error', console.log);
```

Here's the debug log :-

```
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":5,"d":{"speaking":1,"delay":0,"ssrc":371158}}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":66569681578}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":66569681578}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":26930605505}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":26930605505}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":79496921836}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":79496921836}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 40ms.
Running command music:queue.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":33712802512}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":33712802512}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":24138243497}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":24138243497}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":13166311857}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":13166311857}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 43ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":67664333492}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":67664333492}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":37125764206}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":37125764206}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":93951547272}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":93951547272}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 45ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":24135858671}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":24135858671}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":55152836464}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":55152836464}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":40854416435}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":40854416435}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 40ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":5512391576}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":5512391576}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":45106447764}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":45106447764}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":40817416696}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":40817416696}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 67ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":35720124862}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":35720124862}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":30746596945}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":30746596945}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":17419829656}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":17419829656}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 40ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":65665457127}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":65665457127}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":70834746297}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":70834746297}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":92395018869}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":92395018869}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 46ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":79875631149}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":79875631149}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":7259025537}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":7259025537}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":40628799373}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":40628799373}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 41ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":28632941276}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":28632941276}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":50220532802}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":50220532802}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":42549939695}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":42549939695}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 41ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":16937277053}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":16937277053}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":69437133821}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":69437133821}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":57642496053}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":57642496053}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 41ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":62889522438}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":62889522438}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":39924399059}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":39924399059}

<error message here>

[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":61045185967}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":61045185967}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 40ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":27875289189}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":27875289189}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":7676658441}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":7676658441}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":3557602962}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":3557602962}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 40ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":21564175818}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":21564175818}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":35294465928}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":35294465928}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":95461363767}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":95461363767}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 43ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":37687966891}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":37687966891}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":42964005186}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":42964005186}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":58201701635}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":58201701635}
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 45ms.
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] >> {"op":3,"d":2702569957}
[VOICE (796060146048041020:0)]: [WS] << {"op":6,"d":2702569957}
```

which I obtained from :-

```
client.on('debug', console.log);
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated :)

Comment: you are testing on local using windows ?

Comment: @HellCatVN Yes, Windows 10 x64. Node.js version 16

Comment: did you installed ffmpeg . If yes try to replace `djs/opus` with `node-opus` or `opusscript`

Comment: How would I go about installing ffmpeg on my repl? I do not have it on my local system but it works fine without it

Comment: this happen cause music decoder having errors so if you want stable you should setup your own server so that you can manage almost case

Comment: So you are saying that I don't use repl.it for this? I guess that is an option but I will keep looking for a solution

Comment: Yes repl.it is not born to hosting your music bot

Answer (score 1):

OK so I answering my own question. So what happened was that I was running node version 16 on my repl since the default node version was 10 and that did not support `discord.js`. So I had just done `npm i node@latest` which automatically installed version 16. That is a problem because it is non-LTS version of node. So I had to uninstall it by - `npm uninstall node` and install version 14 of node via `npm i node@14` and that simply fixed the issue. Now I just need to use `npx node` instead of `node` on my repl and it works perfectly! If you are having the same issue, I recommend trying that before anything else.